# registering a user with email confirm and captcha?

Tags: language-agnostic

Does it make any sense to include a captcha when registration already requires email confirmation? any added benefit or just a waste of effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither will prevent current bots from getting into your system if that is your reason for doing these.  Usually email confirmation is done to validate that the user gave a correct email address if you have need to contact them (or spam them).  I don't see the value in adding a captcha to that.